# Pulling country from array, then using "if/else" to determine if a redirect is needed

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, if-statement

One of the classes on our website that drops a list of countries to select when trying to order the product has many items. 3 countries - Russia, Belarus and Kazakhstan - need to be separated from the list and redirect the user to a Russian website due to registration conflicts and such. It used to just include a country code in the URL as it entered the order page, and from there based on some countries it would switch languages. The languages are completely irreverent in this case. I located the class that is responsible for the list and the function to proceed to the order page with a certain country indicated. I want to include an "if/else" statement in there, where "if the person selected RU, BY or KZ = redirect to another website" or "else = return country code"
The else seems to be fine, but Dreamweaver keeps telling me there is an issue with the "if" statement line and I tried working around with different ways of writing the syntax with no luck.

```
    <?php

class CountryUtil {

   public static $country_list =
        array(
            'AF'   => 'Afghanistan',
            'AX'   => 'Aland Islands',
            'AL'   => 'Albania',
            'DZ'   => 'Algeria',
            'AS'   => 'American Samoa',
            'AD'   => 'Andorra',
            'AO'   => 'Angola',
            'AI'   => 'Anguilla',
            'AQ'   => 'Antarctica',
            'AG'   => 'Antigua and Barbuda',
            'AR'   => 'Argentina',
            'AM'   => 'Armenia',
            'AW'   => 'Aruba',
            'AU'   => 'Australia',
            'AT'   => 'Austria',
            'AZ'   => 'Azerbaijan',
            'BS'   => 'Bahamas',
            'BH'   => 'Bahrain',
            'BD'   => 'Bangladesh',
            'BB'   => 'Barbados',
            'BY'   => 'Belarus',
            'BE'   => 'Belgium',
            'BZ'   => 'Belize',
            'BJ'   => 'Benin',
            'BM'   => 'Bermuda',
            'BT'   => 'Bhutan',
            'BO'   => 'Bolivia',
            'BA'   => 'Bosnia and Herzegovina',
            'BW'   => 'Botswana',
            'BV'   => 'Bouvet Island',
            'BR'   => 'Brazil',
            'IO'   => 'British Indian Ocean Territory',
            'BN'   => 'Brunei Darussalam',
            'BG'   => 'Bulgaria',
            'BF'   => 'Burkina Faso',
            'BI'   => 'Burundi',
            'KH'   => 'Cambodia',
            'CM'   => 'Cameroon',
            'CA'   => 'Canada',
            'CV'   => 'Cape Verde',
            'KY'   => 'Cayman Islands',
            'CF'   => 'Central African Republic',
            'TD'   => 'Chad',
            'CL'   => 'Chile',
            'CN'   => 'China',
            'CO'   => 'Colombia',
            'KM'   => 'Comoros',
            'CG'   => 'Congo',
            'CK'   => 'Cook Islands',
            'CR'   => 'Costa Rica',
            'CI'   => 'Cote D\'Ivoire',
            'HR'   => 'Croatia',
            'CU'   => 'Cuba',
            'CY'   => 'Cyprus',
            'CZ'   => 'Czech Republic',
            'DK'   => 'Denmark',
            'DJ'   => 'Djibouti',
            'DM'   => 'Dominica',
            'DO'   => 'Dominican Republic',
            'EC'   => 'Ecuador',
            'EG'   => 'Egypt',
            'SV'   => 'El Salvador',
            'GQ'   => 'Equatorial Guinea',
            'ER'   => 'Eritrea',
            'EE'   => 'Estonia',
            'ET'   => 'Ethiopia',
            'FK'   => 'Falkland Islands (Malvinas)',
            'FO'   => 'Faroe Islands',
            'FJ'   => 'Fiji',
            'FI'   => 'Finland',
            'FR'   => 'France',
            'GF'   => 'French Guiana',
            'PF'   => 'French Polynesia',
            'GA'   => 'Gabon',
            'GM'   => 'Gambia',
            'GE'   => 'Georgia',
            'DE'   => 'Germany',
            'GH'   => 'Ghana',
            'GI'   => 'Gibraltar',
            'GR'   => 'Greece',
            'GL'   => 'Greenland',
            'GD'   => 'Grenada',
            'GP'   => 'Guadeloupe',
            'GU'   => 'Guam',
            'GT'   => 'Guatemala',
            'GN'   => 'Guinea',
            'GW'   => 'Guinea-Bissau',
            'GY'   => 'Guyana',
            'HT'   => 'Haiti',
            'HM'   => 'Heard Island and McDonald Islands',
            'VA'   => 'Holy See (Vatican City State)',
            'HN'   => 'Honduras',
            'HK'   => 'Hong Kong',
            'HU'   => 'Hungary',
            'IS'   => 'Iceland',
            'IN'   => 'India',
            'ID'   => 'Indonesia',
            'IR'   => 'Iran, Islamic Republic of',
            'IQ'   => 'Iraq',
            'IE'   => 'Ireland',
            'IL'   => 'Israel',
            'IT'   => 'Italy',
            'JM'   => 'Jamaica',
            'JP'   => 'Japan',
            'JO'   => 'Jordan',
            'KZ'   => 'Kazakhstan',
            'KE'   => 'Kenya',
            'KI'   => 'Kiribati',
            'KR'   => 'Korea, Republic of',
            'KW'   => 'Kuwait',
            'KG'   => 'Kyrgyzstan',
            'LA'   => 'Lao People\'s Democratic Republic',
            'LV'   => 'Latvia',
            'LB'   => 'Lebanon',
            'LS'   => 'Lesotho',
            'LR'   => 'Liberia',
            'LY'   => 'Libyan Arab Jamahiriya',
            'LI'   => 'Liechtenstein',
            'LT'   => 'Lithuania',
            'LU'   => 'Luxembourg',
            'MO'   => 'Macao',
            'MK'   => 'Macedonia, the Former Yugoslav Republic of',
            'MG'   => 'Madagascar',
            'MW'   => 'Malawi',
            'MY'   => 'Malaysia',
            'MV'   => 'Maldives',
            'ML'   => 'Mali',
            'MT'   => 'Malta',
            'MH'   => 'Marshall Islands',
            'MQ'   => 'Martinique',
            'MR'   => 'Mauritania',
            'MU'   => 'Mauritius',
            'YT'   => 'Mayotte',
            'MX'   => 'Mexico',
            'FM'   => 'Micronesia, Federated States of',
            'MD'   => 'Moldova, Republic of',
            'MC'   => 'Monaco',
            'MN'   => 'Mongolia',
            'ME'   => 'Montenegro',
            'MS'   => 'Montserrat',
            'MA'   => 'Morocco',
            'MZ'   => 'Mozambique',
            'MM'   => 'Myanmar',
            'NA'   => 'Namibia',
            'NR'   => 'Nauru',
            'NP'   => 'Nepal',
            'NL'   => 'Netherlands',
            'AN'   => 'Netherlands Antilles',
            'NC'   => 'New Caledonia',
            'NZ'   => 'New Zealand',
            'NI'   => 'Nicaragua',
            'NE'   => 'Niger',
            'NG'   => 'Nigeria',
            'NU'   => 'Niue',
            'NF'   => 'Norfolk Island',
            'MP'   => 'Northern Mariana Islands',
            'NO'   => 'Norway',
            'OM'   => 'Oman',
            'PK'   => 'Pakistan',
            'PW'   => 'Palau',
            'PS'   => 'Palestinian Territory',
            'PA'   => 'Panama',
            'PG'   => 'Papua New Guinea',
            'PY'   => 'Paraguay',
            'PE'   => 'Peru',
            'PH'   => 'Philippines',
            'PL'   => 'Poland',
            'PT'   => 'Portugal',
            'PR'   => 'Puerto Rico',
            'QA'   => 'Qatar',
            'RE'   => 'Reunion',
            'RO'   => 'Romania',
            'RU'   => 'Russian Federation',
            'RW'   => 'Rwanda',
            'SH'   => 'Saint Helena',
            'KN'   => 'Saint Kitts and Nevis',
            'LC'   => 'Saint Lucia',
            'PM'   => 'Saint Pierre and Miquelon',
            'VC'   => 'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines',
            'WS'   => 'Samoa',
            'SM'   => 'San Marino',
            'ST'   => 'Sao Tome and Principe',
            'SA'   => 'Saudi Arabia',
            'SN'   => 'Senegal',
            'RS'   => 'Serbia',
            'SC'   => 'Seychelles',
            'SL'   => 'Sierra Leone',
            'SG'   => 'Singapore',
            'SK'   => 'Slovakia',
            'SI'   => 'Slovenia',
            'SB'   => 'Solomon Islands',
            'SO'   => 'Somalia',
            'ZA'   => 'South Africa',
            'ES'   => 'Spain',
            'LK'   => 'Sri Lanka',
            'SD'   => 'Sudan',
            'SR'   => 'Suriname',
            'SZ'   => 'Swaziland',
            'SE'   => 'Sweden',
            'CH'   => 'Switzerland',
            'SY'   => 'Syrian Arab Republic',
            'TW'   => 'Taiwan',
            'TJ'   => 'Tajikistan',
            'TZ'   => 'Tanzania, United Republic of',
            'TH'   => 'Thailand',
            'TG'   => 'Togo',
            'TK'   => 'Tokelau',
            'TO'   => 'Tonga',
            'TT'   => 'Trinidad and Tobago',
            'TN'   => 'Tunisia',
            'TR'   => 'Turkey',
            'TM'   => 'Turkmenistan',
            'TC'   => 'Turks and Caicos Islands',
            'TV'   => 'Tuvalu',
            'UG'   => 'Uganda',
            'UA'   => 'Ukraine',
            'AE'   => 'United Arab Emirates',
            'GB'   => 'United Kingdom',
            'US'   => 'United States',
            'UM'   => 'United States Minor Outlying Islands',
            'UY'   => 'Uruguay',
            'UZ'   => 'Uzbekistan',
            'VU'   => 'Vanuatu',
            'VE'   => 'Venezuela',
            'VN'   => 'Vietnam',
            'VG'   => 'Virgin Islands, British',
            'VI'   => 'Virgin Islands, U.S.',
            'WF'   => 'Wallis and Futuna',
            'YE'   => 'Yemen',
            'ZM'   => 'Zambia',
            'ZW'   => 'Zimbabwe',
        );


            if(public static $country_list == 'RU', 'BY', 'KZ') {
                Header("Location: http://medolife-escozine.ru/cart");
            }
            else {
                public static function getList
                return self::$country_list;}

?>
```

Update per answer from @MikeBrant below:

There is another "layout.php" file that is responsible for the general structure of the website's pages. In there, the drop down menu's code is:

```
<?php $countryList = CountryUtil::getList(); /* ups! MVC */?>
<select id="country-sel">
    <option>Select country</option>
    <option value="us">United States</option>
        <?php foreach ( $countryList as $k => $v ) : 
        ?>

    <option value="<?php echo strtolower($k)?>"<?php echo $s?>><?php echo $v?></option>
        <? endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Update 11/05/2014 2:27 pm AST:

Judging from the code for the dropdown menu that I shared later, `$countryList = CountryUtil::getList()` so I tried using that, as well as `$countryList = array('RU', 'BY', 'KZ');` with no luck. The thing is, like I said, this website is built beyond the understanding of many developers who attempted to tackle it, yet alone me. Each page uses at least 4 different PHP files, which in combination create a full page. It's the page content file, the layout.php for the general website layout, the _menu.php for certain image changes in the nabigation bar on each page, and _title.php with only an echo for the page title. I've spent hours trying to insert the provided code for "if */country is RU, BY, KZ*/ then redirect", that you were kind enough to provide, into different sections of the mentioned files with no changes whatsoever. None of them contain a , so I was then looking for the file/code that is responsible for combining all the 4 or more files to create a webpage, but with no luck. I'm going to look into finding a freelancer to see if he or she can figure this out. Any additional suggestions would be much appreciated nonetheless!

Answer (score 0):

That if/else statement can't just run in a class outside of some method. Also you likely wouldn't check for the redirection at the point in time where you are trying to access the country. There must be something in the code that outside the class that would call to make the determinatio of when to redirect.  You have not shown any context for this.

Your class may look like:

```
class CountryUtil {

   public static $country_list =
        array(
            'AF'   => 'Afghanistan',
            /* omitted for clarity */

            'ZW'   => 'Zimbabwe',
        );

   public static $redirect_to_russia_list = array('RU', 'BY', 'KZ');

   public static function getList() {
       return self::$country_list;
   }

   public static function needsRussiaRedirect($country_code) {
       if (in_array($country_code, self::$redirect_to_russia_list)) {
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }
}
```

Then at appropriate place in code outside the class where redirection decision needs to be made (some time before any content is rendered to browser).  You would call this function like:

```
$country_code = ...; // assume current country code is set somewhere
if (CountryUtil::needsRussiaRedirect($country_code)) {
    header("Location: http://medolife-escozine.ru/cart");
}
```

Per your updated content, this portion of code is not really related at all. This is just where country dropdown is populated.  I imagine once the form is posted is when you want to do your redirect.  IN that case you would need to place redirect code  at beginning of that page where form is posting to.

Comment: Thank you for the help again, @Mike! I'm starting to understand this a bit clearer, but in the section `($country_code = ...;` does the ellipsis need to be replaced with something, or is that part of the code where `($country_code` equals whatever the user selected?

Comment: @Ncast I wasn't sure how you received the value for the country code that you are trying to use for comparison, so I just used `...` along with a comment that I am assuming you are setting this somewhere in previous code before getting to this `if` condition.

Comment: forgot to mention I posted an update and I really appreciate your help on this!